# ng-bind-html change the html structure, why?

Tags: html, angularjs, sanitize, ng-bind-html

I get HTML code from the backend via $http of AngularJS, and log the code retrieved and is OK, but to see it in the browser, the html structure changed.
This is the code that I get:

```
<a href="  http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <figure>
       <img class="img-responsive" src="/sites/Satellite;jsessionid=pk_tbxorbyJ4KrsWxo1jaVBFYvQPx1VovEs2GpjWziIk6cFaL50_!650994948?blobcol=urldata&amp;blobkey=id&amp;blobtable=MungoBlobs&amp;blobwhere=1462843196206&amp;ssbinary=true" />

    </figure>
    <p> Some text</p>
</a>
```

and this is what the browser displays:

```
<a href="  http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
</a>
<figure>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/sites/Satellite;jsessionid=pk_tbxorbyJ4KrsWxo1jaVBFYvQPx1VovEs2GpjWziIk6cFaL50_!650994948?blobcol=urldata&amp;blobkey=id&amp;blobtable=MungoBlobs&amp;blobwhere=1462843196206&amp;ssbinary=true">
</figure>
<p> some text</p>
```

Then I did the following test, log the code retrieved

> $log.debug(vm.myHtml);

and then sanitize the code with

> $log.debug($sce.getTrustedHtml(vm.myHtml))

and I get the same previous difference.

Comment: Do you have `<!doctype html>` at the top of you root HTML?

Comment: What's your browser? [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/b66pq0?p=preview) works on my browser(Google Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m)

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes I have <!doctype html>

Comment: @YinGang I test in Google Chrome Versión 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) for Mac

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?  I seem to be having the same problem with having nested block elements within anchor tags.  I have played around with some other peoples ng-bind-html demos and they seem to allow nesting of block elements just fine.  Not quite sure why it's not allowing this nesting.  I've tried on both chrome and firefox and both the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and so played around with the Plunker available on the [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

I then modified it by placing some `<h1>` tags within `<a>` tags (see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/62UnHRv56yMqVWTH2cVs?p=preview)).  The good news was that it worked in this most basic case.  This had me scratching my head for ages.

In the end, I was just guessing that maybe the version of ngSanitize that I was using was maybe a little old and at some point they had slightly changed the way the tags were mapped, split and then rendered.  I looked through the history but couldn't find anything.  In the end, i updated to 1.5.7 the same as the version in the plunker.  And smiling again :)